# Circular dependencies and functions

Tags: c++

I have two headers, A and B. They look like this:

```
// A.h
#include "B.h";

class A {
    // stuff
    AFunction(B* b);
    OtherFunction();
}

// B.h
class A;

BFunction(A* a);
```

This is my first attempt at solving a circular dependency, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing. My problem is the following: BFunction, at some point, calls `a->OtherFunction();`. I get an error since OtherFunction is not forward declared, and I cannot forward declare it either, apparently. The situation is symmetrical (AFunction calls b->SomeOtherFunction()), so I wouldn't be able to fix it by swapping the include and forward declaration.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You still need to include A.h in your B.cpp implementation file.

Comment: Both `.cpp` files should include both `.h` files.

Comment: Just use a forward declaration in each header file.

Comment: A forward declaration is not enough if he is going to use anything of the other object in the header file.

Comment: FYI you can use values instead of pointers as function parameters here.

Comment: @Pubby I thought that the compiler must know the size of each function parameter and the return values while compiling the class. Didn't quite get the reason why your suggestion is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both .cpp files should include both .h files.

A simplified example:

```
// A.h
void funcA();

// A.c
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void funcA() { funcB(); }

// B.h
void funcB();

// B.c
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void funcB() { funcA(); }
```

Remember, unless you're dealing with templated classes, *declarations* go in *header files*, *definitions* (implementations) go in *source files*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need anything about A or B which is not just assigning a pointer of their type then you **MUST** move the related code in a .cpp file since you can't include them in a circular way. Solution is like the following:

**A.h**

```
class B; // forward declaration

class A {
  B* b;

  // legal, you don't need to know anything about B
  void set(B* b) { this->b = b; } 

  // must be implemented in .cpp because it needs to know B
  void doSomethingWithB(); 
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
#include "A.h"

void A::doSomethingWithB() {
  b->whatever();
```

**B.h**

```
class A

class B {
  void methodWithA(A* a);
};
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

void B::methodWithA(A* a) {
  a->whatever();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are **using only pointers** in your class definitions, you can **forward declare the other class** in front of each class in the .h files and then **include both .h** files in your .cpp files.

**Move any code** from the definition of the class in the .h files to the definitions of the functions in **the .cpp** to reduce any dependencies. i.e Define all functions using other class details in the .cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

Change from member function `A::OtherFunction()`  to stand alone function `OtherFunction(A*)`.